# Non-dimensionalization of Navier-Stokes equations multiphase flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, flow, navier-stokes

I am currently dealing with multiphase flows and have to use the non-dimensional form of the Navier-Stokes equations (NSE).
In the scientific literature I found various formulations (and almost no explaining o how they get them) but I wanted to get to the point by myself as well. Although the procedure should be simple, the results do not lign up and I cannot wrap around my head on why.
NSE can be written for incompressible fluids as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbb{u}}{\mathrm{D}t}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\mathbb{\nabla}p+\mathbb{g}+\frac{\mu}{\rho}\Delta\mathbb{u}
\end{equation}
where the ratio $\frac{\mathrm{D}}{\mathrm{D}t}$ represent the material derivative, $\mathbb{u}$ is the fluid velocity, $\rho$ the density, $\mathbb{g}$ the gravitational acceleration and $\mu$ the dynamic viscosity. Also, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator.

With surface tension, the equation becomes (CSF formulation of the surface tension)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbb{u}}{\mathrm{D}t}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\mathbb{\nabla}p+\mathbb{g}+\frac{\mu}{\rho}\Delta\mathbb{u}+\frac{\sigma\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\rho}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is the coefficient of surface tension, $\kappa$ is the curvature, $\hat{\mathbb{n}}$ is the normal unit vector to the interface surface and $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ a Dirac delta function (smeared out version).

Introducing the following dimensionless variables (marked with $'$):
\begin{equation}
x'L=\mathbb{x} \hspace{5mm}
u'U=\mathbb{u} \hspace{5mm}
g'g=\mathbb{g} \hspace{5mm}
\nabla'=\mathbb{\nabla}L \hspace{5mm}
\Delta'=\Delta L^2 \hspace{5mm}
p=p'\rho U^2 \hspace{5mm}
t'=tU/L
\end{equation}
I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{U^2}{L} \frac{\mathrm{D}u'}{\mathrm{D}t'}=-\frac{U^2}{\rho}\frac{\nabla'}{L}p'+g'g+\frac{\mu}{\rho}\frac{U}{L^2}\Delta' u'+\frac{\sigma\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\rho}
\end{equation}
and, after multiplying both sides of the equation for $L/U^2$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{D}u'}{\mathrm{D}t'}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla'p'+\frac{g'gL}{U^2}+\frac{\mu}{\rho}\frac{1}{LU}\Delta' u'+\frac{\sigma\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\rho}\frac{L}{U^2}
\end{equation}
Now, after introducing the well-known Reynolds and Froude numbers
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Re}=\frac{\rho LU}{\mu} \hspace{10mm} \mathrm{Fr}=\frac{U}{\sqrt{gL}}
\end{equation}
it follows that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{D}u'}{\mathrm{D}t'}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla'p'+\frac{1}{\mathrm{Fr}^2}g'+\frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}}\Delta' u'+\frac{\sigma\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\rho}\frac{L}{U^2}
\end{equation}
Until here no problem.

However, for the manipulation of the surface tension (SF) form, some authors (e.g. "An improved level set method for incompressible two-phase flows". Sussman et al., 1998) use the Weber number:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{We}=\frac{\rho LU^2}{\sigma}
\end{equation}
Plugging this latter in the SF term though, I get:
\begin{equation}
SF'=\frac{\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}L^2}{\mathrm{We}}
\end{equation}
instead of
\begin{equation}
SF'=\frac{\kappa\hat{\mathbb{n}}\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\mathrm{We}}
\end{equation}

I dare to think that this latter formulation is incorrect due to the incontrovertible principle of dimensional homogeneity.

$\kappa$ is measured (I hereinafter use the S.I. units for simplicity) in [1/m],  $\hat{\mathbb{n}}$ is dimensionless [-] (unit vector) and the delta function has as unit of measure the inverse of its argument (which is a distance function) [1/m]. Thus
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dimensionless \hspace{3mm}number}[-] \neq \frac{[1/m][-][1/m]}{\mathrm{dimensionless \hspace{3mm}number}[-]}=[1/m^2]
\end{equation}

If someone can explain to me if I made some mistake I would greatly appreciate it.

Note:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbb{n}}=\frac{\mathbb{\nabla}{d}}{|\mathbb{\nabla}{d}|}=[-]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\kappa=\mathbb{\nabla}\cdot\hat{\mathbb{n}}=[1/m]
\end{equation}

Comment: Since when is a surface tension term included in the Navier Stokes equations?  Surface tension occurs at a free surface, and is treated as a boundary condition rather than a term in the momentum balance.

Comment: As I wrote in the question title, I'm dealing with multiphase flows; to model the interfaces between the phases, surface tension must be taken into account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because check-my-work questions are generally not appropriate for physics SE. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, your $\kappa$ and $\delta_\varepsilon$ are still dimensional quantities, both in the units of [1/m]. To make them dimensionless, you just need to multiply by characteristic length $L$:

$\kappa' = \kappa L$, $\delta'_\varepsilon=\delta_\varepsilon L$

Then, $SF' = \frac{\kappa'\hat{n}\delta'_\varepsilon}{\rm We}$ is a dimensionless quantity.